# Implement memory efficient XLSX reader in JAVA using poi with XSSF and SAX but didn't know how to get formula?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax, xssf

I am trying to implement `.xlsx` a reader using POI in java in that my main concern is the memory so I implemented it using XSSF and SAX here is the reference for code which I use [Event API (XSSF with SAX)](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-apache-poi-library)
but the formula is one of the main things with a cell property that I want to read, for example, I want to read cell name(C12), cell value, cell formula, etc. but I am struggling with formula have no clue how to get without using the workbook. Because if I use the workbook there is an issue with memory.

Can anybody help me out with a problem?

Comment: The formula is written inside the cell in the `<f>` tag, what's the problem?

Comment: @Gagravarr yes i got this but i am stuck with how to read that f tag value
<c r="E6">
<f>SUM(D6,F6)</f>
<v>10</v>
</c>

Comment: You've got your cell reference, formula string and last-calculated value, looks good to me! What's your problem here?

Comment: @Gagravarr I guess I am not able to explain the exact problem. So  <c r="E6"> <f>SUM(D6,F6)</f> <v>10</v> </c> this is what i get when i manually convert xlsx to zip and find sheet.xml now I wrote code for read cell reference an cell value but don't know how to write code to get cell formula not formua value.

Comment: Why not [follow the Apache POI example code](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)?

Comment: @Gagravarr thank you that was really helpful can you give one more favor with the same example which you have suggested above can you tell me if I want to read cell property ex font, font-size, font-family, border, etc.  how it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As told in [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api):

> ... you can get at the underlying XML data, and process it yourself.
> This is intended for intermediate developers who are willing to learn
> a little bit of low level structure of .xlsx files, and who are happy
> processing XML in java. Its relatively simple to use, but requires a
> basic understanding of the file structure.

So at first you needs to know how a `*.xlsx` file is structured and what the `XML` in it's parts means. Also you needs to know how `XML` parsing using `SAX` works. For example what it means that a `ContentHandler` has methods `startElement`, `endElement` and `characters`. Also you needs to know when they get called and what the given parameters mean.

If all this is clear, then you could begin to program. The `ExampleEventUserModel`  example in [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) has very basic functionality to understand the basics. It only gets string contents from shared strings table and all other contents exactly as they are stored in `v` elements. Your linked `DZone` example is even more simplyfied. It only gets string contents from shared strings table.

I can provide a more complete example which also gets formulas from `f` elements, if any, and also uses a `StylesTable` additional to the `SharedStringsTable` to get the `XSSFCellStyle` of the cell, if the `s` attribute points to a cell style. This `XSSFCellStyle` then contains the number format but also font settings, border settigs, ..., if any.

Example:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class ExampleEventUserModel {

    public void processAllSheets(String filename) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);

        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
        StylesTable st = r.getStylesTable();
        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst, st);

        Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
        while(sheets.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
            InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
            sheet.close();
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }


    public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst, StylesTable st) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        XMLReader parser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst, st);
        parser.setContentHandler(handler);
        return parser;
    }


    private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        private SharedStringsTable sst;
        private StylesTable st;
        private String lastCharacters; // characters cache to collect character content between startElement and eneElement
        private String formula; // stores the formula, if any
        private String content; // stores the content, if any
        private boolean nextValueIsSSTString; // indicates that next value is from SharedStringsTable 
        private boolean nextValueIsStyledNumeric; // indicates that next value is a styled numeric value
        private XSSFCellStyle cellStyle; // stores the cell style, if any
        private DataFormatter formatter; // used to format the styled numeric values

        private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst, StylesTable st) {
            this.sst = sst;
            this.st = st;
            this.formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US, true);
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                                 Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // c => start of cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // print the cell reference
                System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");

                // get the cell type
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");

                // figure out if the value is an index in the SST
                this.nextValueIsSSTString = false;
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                    this.nextValueIsSSTString = true;
                } 

                // figure out if the cell has style
                this.cellStyle = null;
                String styleIdx = attributes.getValue("s");
                if (styleIdx != null) {
                    int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(styleIdx);
                    this.cellStyle = st.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
                    // print that there is cell style for this cell
                    System.out.print("CellStyle: " + this.cellStyle + " - ");
                }

                // figure out if the value is an styled numeric value or date
                this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric = false;
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("n") || cellType == null) {
                    if (this.cellStyle != null) {
                        this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric = true;
                    }
                } 

            }

            // clear characters cache after each element
            this.lastCharacters = "";
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {

            // f => end of formula in a cell
            if(name.equals("f")) {
                this.formula = lastCharacters;
                // print formula
                System.out.print("Formula: " + this.formula + " - ");
            }

            // v => end of value of a cell
            if(name.equals("v")) {

                this.content = this.lastCharacters;

                // process shared string value
                if(this.nextValueIsSSTString) {
                    int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastCharacters);
                    this.content = sst.getItemAt(idx).getString();
                    nextValueIsSSTString = false;
                }

                // process styled numeric value
                if(this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric) {
                    String formatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
                    int formatIndex = cellStyle.getDataFormat();                    
                    if (formatString == null) {
                        // formatString could not be found, so it must be a builtin format.
                        formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(formatIndex);
                    }
                    double value = Double.valueOf(this.content);
                    this.content = formatter.formatRawCellContents(value, formatIndex, formatString);
                    nextValueIsStyledNumeric = false;
                }

            }

            // c => end of a cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // print content
                System.out.println("Content: " + this.content);
                this.content = "";
            }
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            this.lastCharacters += new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExampleEventUserModel example = new ExampleEventUserModel();
        //example.processAllSheets(args[0]);
        example.processAllSheets("ExcelExample.xlsx");
    }
}
```

---

Apache POI made changes to their code but have not updated all the examples.

Using current Apache POI 5.2.5 the example above would must look like so:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

//import org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper;
import org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
//import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStrings;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class ExampleEventUserModel {

    public void processAllSheets(String filename) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);

        //SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
        SharedStrings sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
        StylesTable st = r.getStylesTable();
        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst, st);

        Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
        while(sheets.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
            InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
            sheet.close();
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }


    public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStrings sst, StylesTable st) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        XMLReader parser = XMLHelper.newXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst, st);
        parser.setContentHandler(handler);
        return parser;
    }


    private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        private SharedStrings sst;
        private StylesTable st;
        private String lastCharacters; // characters cache to collect character content between startElement and eneElement
        private String formula; // stores the formula, if any
        private String content; // stores the content, if any
        private boolean nextValueIsSSTString; // indicates that next value is from SharedStrings 
        private boolean nextValueIsStyledNumeric; // indicates that next value is a styled numeric value
        private XSSFCellStyle cellStyle; // stores the cell style, if any
        private DataFormatter formatter; // used to format the styled numeric values

        private SheetHandler(SharedStrings sst, StylesTable st) {
            this.sst = sst;
            this.st = st;
            this.formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US, true);
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                                 Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // c => start of cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // print the cell reference
                System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");

                // get the cell type
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");

                // figure out if the value is an index in the SST
                this.nextValueIsSSTString = false;
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                    this.nextValueIsSSTString = true;
                } 

                // figure out if the cell has style
                this.cellStyle = null;
                String styleIdx = attributes.getValue("s");
                if (styleIdx != null) {
                    int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(styleIdx);
                    this.cellStyle = st.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
                    // print that there is cell style for this cell
                    System.out.print("CellStyle: " + this.cellStyle + " - ");
                }

                // figure out if the value is an styled numeric value or date
                this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric = false;
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("n") || cellType == null) {
                    if (this.cellStyle != null) {
                        this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric = true;
                    }
                } 

            }

            // clear characters cache after each element
            this.lastCharacters = "";
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {

            // f => end of formula in a cell
            if(name.equals("f")) {
                this.formula = lastCharacters;
                // print formula
                System.out.print("Formula: " + this.formula + " - ");
            }

            // v => end of value of a cell
            if(name.equals("v")) {

                this.content = this.lastCharacters;

                // process shared string value
                if(this.nextValueIsSSTString) {
                    int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastCharacters);
                    this.content = sst.getItemAt(idx).getString();
                    nextValueIsSSTString = false;
                }

                // process styled numeric value
                if(this.nextValueIsStyledNumeric) {
                    String formatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
                    int formatIndex = cellStyle.getDataFormat();                    
                    if (formatString == null) {
                        // formatString could not be found, so it must be a builtin format.
                        formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(formatIndex);
                    }
                    double value = Double.valueOf(this.content);
                    this.content = formatter.formatRawCellContents(value, formatIndex, formatString);
                    nextValueIsStyledNumeric = false;
                }

            }

            // c => end of a cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // print content
                System.out.println("Content: " + this.content);
                this.content = "";
            }
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            this.lastCharacters += new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExampleEventUserModel example = new ExampleEventUserModel();
        //example.processAllSheets(args[0]);
        example.processAllSheets("ExcelExample.xlsx");
    }
}
```